# Disable InputScope Automatic Completion TextBox

Tags: windows-phone-7

I want to disable the automatic completion in my textbox by Windows Phone 7 keyboard inputscope in code.

How would I do this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Automatic completion is done when you have `Text` InputScope. Change it to `Default` and completion will be gone.